# Jquery Cookies code executing without going to the index page

Tags: jquery, cookies

Please check the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var href;
if(href!=null)
{
setContainerHtml($.cookie("activeElementHref"));
};

$('nav ul li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    href= $(this).attr('href');
    $.cookie("activeElementHref", href) 
    setContainerHtml(href);
});
}); 
function setContainerHtml(href) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "baker.php",
        data:{send_txt: href},
        success: function(data){
            $('#aside-right, #intro').css('display','none');
            $('#main-content').fadeOut('10', function (){
            $('#main-content').css('width','700px');
            $('#main-content').css('margin','-30px 0 0 100px');
            $('#main-content').html(data);
            $('#main-content').fadeIn('8000');
            });
        }   
    });
}
```

The cookie is not working the clicked link state is not preserved when i click refresh index html page is displayed

Comment: it seems like `href` will always be `null` on DOM ready and the if-statement `if (href != null)` will always return true. Why not just remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Href is null instead of empty string:

```
var href;  // variable is set to null...

if(href != '') // ... null is different than empty string...
{
    // ...so the code always enters here.
    setContainerHtml($.cookie("activeElementHref"));
};
```

I think it should be:

```
var href = $.cookie("activeElementHref");  //Read the cookie

if(href !== null) 
{
    setContainerHtml(href );
};
```

Comment: i edited my code but now what happens that the cookie state is not preserved

Comment: Try the code from my update. I think you're not reading the cookie before checking the condition.

Comment: Its working! Now how to delete the cookie when the browser window is closed? I have to delete the cookie as when i again open the page the cookie preserved state page is opened not the index page

Comment: You can set a cookie expiration time. The cookie will be deleted after that time.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
    var href;
    href!='';
```

Is true, if you using Chrome, go to Console and execute it. So the first time setContainerHtml is called.

Try this insteed:

```
    var href;
    href!=null;
```

Or if you really want to use !='' just put var href=""; in the first line...

Comment: i edited my code but now what happens that the cookie state is not preserved

Comment: Where do you read the cookie? 
Try something like this:

var href = $.cookie("activeElementHref");  //Read the cookie

if(href != null) // Check if the cookie exist
{
   if(href != "") // Check if its empty? Maybe you can ignore it
   {
       setContainerHtml(href );
   };
};